# TestNG and DataProvider - how to handle good failed tests

Tags: testing, testng, testng-dataprovider

My queston is:
When you do a test for logging page and you use different parameters and some of them causes our tests failing then what you do with them?
I mean you have test with let say 5 parameters - 3 of them are positive and test passes, and 2 of them are negative and test fails. You also run your tests everyday from TeamCity/Jenkins automaticaly. So if anyone new will look at them then he sees that 2 tests fails thinking that something is wrong. How do you handle this situation? Do you somehow mark intentionaly failed tests as passed or something like that? if yes, how do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are using for reporting but you can put the non-true fail test cases in "skip" status in TestNG or "skip" / "error" / "warning" status in ExtentReport.